# Sheet Names stored in array, Google Apps Script only Accessing first two

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been using Google Apps Script along with spreadsheet to create a spreadsheet that watches a set of stocks. I have assigned each stock it's own sheet and set up the function with a day trigger so that it refreshes all of the information each day. I spent so much time debugging a lot and finally got it working perfectly for the first two sheets. I now added 3 more and it's not doing anything for them.

```html
function XMLDATAONDAY() {

    for (r=0;r<5;r++){
        var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        var sheets= ["HSY","AAPL","CENX","MSFT","TSLA"]
        var sheet=ss.getSheetByName(sheets[r])
        var i=14
        var dateSrc=sheet.getRange(2,5) 
        var stockPrice = sheet.getRange(5,4).getValue()
        var displayCell= sheet.getRange(2,4)
        var date = dateSrc.getValue()

        SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IOBQpdUr0fq_clie-0AOnCAN87qTy9Yn1h79akMJ7uc/edit#gid=0');
        for (i=14;i<366;i++) {
            var sheets= ["HSY","AAPL","CENX","MSFT","TSLA"]
            var stockCell=sheet.getRange(i,2)
            var dateCell=sheet.getRange(i,1)

            if(stockCell.getValue()== ""){
                sheet.getRange(14,1).copyFormatToRange(sheet, 1, 1, i, i)
                sheet.getRange(14,2).copyFormatToRange(sheet, 2, 2, i, i)
                dateCell.setValue(date);
                stockCell.setValue(stockPrice);
                i=400;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's probably something that I'm just overlooking, but I just can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
i=400;
```

Should probably be changed to:

```
break;
```

I'm guessing that you are setting `i` to 400 in order to stop the next loop from running?

There is a duplicate variable assignment for `sheets`.  It's an array literal.  Only define that once, and put it outside of the `for` loops.  Put the variable assignment for `ss` outside of the loop also.  If you do not assign `r` with a statement, the code still runs without any noticeable difference, but without a `var` statement, the variable is defined in the global scope.

The statement to open a spreadsheet by URL is not doing anything.  It's not assigned to a variable, so I'm not sure what that line is for.

```
function XMLDATAONDAY() {
  var date,dateCell,dateSrc,displayCell,i,r,sheet,sheets,ss,stockCell,stockPrice;

  sheets = ["HSY","AAPL","CENX","MSFT","TSLA"];
  ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  r=0;
  
  for (r=0;r<5;r++){
    sheet=ss.getSheetByName(sheets[r])
    i=14
    dateSrc=sheet.getRange(2,5) 
    stockPrice = sheet.getRange(5,4).getValue()
    displayCell = sheet.getRange(2,4)
    date = dateSrc.getValue()
 
    //SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/sheet_ID_HERE/edit#gid=0');
    for (i=14;i<366;i++) {
      stockCell=sheet.getRange(i,2)
      dateCell=sheet.getRange(i,1)
     
      if(stockCell.getValue()== ""){
        sheet.getRange(14,1).copyFormatToRange(sheet, 1, 1, i, i)
        sheet.getRange(14,2).copyFormatToRange(sheet, 2, 2, i, i)
        dateCell.setValue(date);
        stockCell.setValue(stockPrice);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```